# Dataset for globular star cluster

Tags: data-analysis, globular-clusters, star-cluster

**Where can I find the 
dataset(s) for a globular star cluster?**

The datasets should have the coordinates, color index (for different wavelengths) , magnitude etc. of every star in the cluster.

I want to do data analysis on it just for fun.

Comment: Do you have access to journal papers through a university? There are loads of catalogues available if you can get at them, if not it is a bit trickier to find a non-paywalled option, but let me know and I can try to find you a paper,

Comment: No I don't have access to them. Actually I am going to participate in a competition next week . And  I have to do data analysis to find some parameters or identify  clusters on dataset containing "locations", "magnitude" etc of globular star cluster. So I want to practice for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by doing a search on [VizieR](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR), select "Globular_Clusters" from the right-hand list box (this tells me there are around 900 catalogs in this category) and click "Find Catalogs".

Some of the returned results will be catalogues of stars within a given cluster, the density map on the right-hand side of the list will show these as a single point. Other catalogues will be lists of multiple globular clusters, the density map will show there is data from all over the sky.

I hope that's useful for you!